# Android ViewPager inside Fragment loaded only once v2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My question is similtar to this:

[Android ViewPager Inside Fragment Loaded Only Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25985576/android-viewpager-inside-fragment-loaded-only-once)

The difference is that its answer doesn't work for me.

I have 4 fragments. Inside one of these fragments there is a **Fragment X** with `ViewPager` that switch betwen two other fragments. The first time I load the `FragmentX` the `ViewPager` works fine. The problem is if I switch to one of the other 4 fragments, when I go back to the `FragmentX` the `ViewPager` has nothing inside.

**Fragment X**

```
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_campus, container, false);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Mapa"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Eventos"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    vpPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
    vpPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            vpPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

**PageAdapter**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int NUM_ITEMS = 2;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return MapFragment.newInstance(0);
            case 1:
                return EventosFragment.newInstance(1);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }


}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    ...
    if (...) {
        if (campusFragment == null) // the problem is not solved by commenting this condition
            campusFragment = new CampusFragment(); // Fragment X
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, campusFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: How you go back to the `FragmentX` again? Simply by clicking the back button?

Comment: With a Navigation Drawer