# PagerSlidingStrip is also loading another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have implemented Pager Sliding Strip and it is working totally fine.

I have 5 tabs each containing different fragment. When I click on 2nd tab to load respective fragment, it also load details of 3rd fragment, it showing the toast I coded in 3rd tab's fragment.

this is totally ruined the apps performance, How come I solve this problem I don't have any idea whats actually going on.

I am working on a really big project I cannot post the whole code.

Please Help me with this, I will post the respective code on demand.

Regards.

EDIT

Notification Fragment which is loading another fragment

```
    ListView notification_listview;
ArrayList<FragmentNotificationDTO> arraylist;
NotificationAdapter adapter;
private static View notificationView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (notificationView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) notificationView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(notificationView);
    }
    notificationView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification,
            container, false);
    initLayout(notificationView);
    loadData();
    return notificationView;
}

private void initLayout(View view) {
    notification_listview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.notification_listview);
    arraylist = new ArrayList<FragmentNotificationDTO>();
    adapter = new NotificationAdapter(mContext, arraylist);
    notification_listview.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

This is Food Fragment which is loaded also when we click on Notification Tab

```
  private static View foodlistView;
RelativeLayout rl_foodshare, rl_foodrequested, rl_foodkitchen;
TextView tv_foodshare, tv_foodrequested, tv_foodkitchen;
ImageView img_foodshare, img_foodrequested, img_foodkitchen;
Fragment fr;
FragmentManager fm;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (foodlistView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) foodlistView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(foodlistView);
    }
    foodlistView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location_list,
            container, false);
    initLayout(foodlistView);
    ChangeFragment(1);
    return foodlistView;
}
```

MainActivity.java which contains the PagerSlidingStrip & View Pager

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

    PagerSlidingTabStrip PGSTRIP = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    PGSTRIP.setViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
}
```

Comment: Check if you have any instance of any view with same name in more then one fragment. I had similar problem yesterday, this was the issue.

Comment: @ParsaniaHardik Let Me Check

Comment: @ParsaniaHardik is checked all the fragments its totally fine. in case I missed something I posted the code above please check and explain if I have any issues

Comment: It is by design - View pager loads tabs in advance

Comment: @Skynet ThankYou for information, How can i avoid it

Comment: can you put your activity.java code?

Comment: Read up on: `pager.setOffscreenPageLimit();` - Just Google that

Comment: set  pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);

Comment: skynet is right it is by design

Comment: @ParsaniaHardik I have edited py question with MainActivity.Java
@Skynet I implemented `pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);` in `MainActivity`
But its not working

Comment: @ankitagrawal I implemented setOffscreen but not working please check my question I posted the code

Comment: Actually I did not intend to mean `setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` - this will not work for you, instead of 0 you should put in the number of all the fragments in your pager. You should implement it like `setOffScreenPageLimit(5)` - if that does not work for you try with: `setUserVisibleHint` - that is an override method.

Comment: @Skynet yes I done that as well but now when I am on first tab its loading the 5th tab fragment :/

Comment: It will keep all your tabs in memory, you only need to load them once at the start. Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485848/how-load-fragment-in-viewpager-only-when-its-selected)

Comment: Oh ThankYou I got your point. But anyway to restrict it to only that tab which is visible to user @Skynet

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by overriding this method in each of my fragment and then calling the loading method when fragment's visibility is true to user.

```
    @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // load data here
    }else{
        // fragment is no longer visible
    }
}
```