# setOffscreenPageLimit loads all fragments together?

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I have an android app with a `MainActivity` which implements a menu with 5 buttons. Each button activates a different `fragment`.

Without using the `"setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)"`, every time I go from fragment to fragment, each fragment loads every single time. 
Using:

```
setOffscreenPageLimit(5)
```

I understand that loads all of my 5 main fragments when starting my application. But I don't want this, because it is too heavy.

I want to implement this:
"Load every fragment only when the user activates it, through choosing the menu button.Then keep it on memory , so when user goes back to this fragment, you don't have to load it again."

Comment: "each fragment loads every single time" -- it shouldn't. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are setting up your `ViewPager` and explain, in detail, how you are determining that "each fragment loads every single time".

Answer (score 0):

From the scratchy details you have provided, I understand that, you want to show fragment when it's displayed on the screen, you don't want it to load when fragment is in background. For this you can try this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25001920/6383029