# How to call webservices when a fragment is visible inside a view pager in android

Tags: android

I am using a view pager, where i am adding 3 fragments. I can redirect to Fragment A, or by swiping from Fragment B. How can i restrict the call of web services in Fragment A when i navigate to fragment B.

Comment: I have used the set user visibility approach, but it doesn't seem to work fully. Each time i navigate to Fragment B, the on Create View of Fragment A is being called and get User visibility Hint method returns true.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12523627/5912570) using setMenuVisibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how load fragment in ViewPager only when its selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485848/how-load-fragment-in-viewpager-only-when-its-selected)