# Android load fragment content only when it is visible

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a single activity which has a tabPageIndicator at the bottom of the screen. [image: Please see screenshot]. The first four icons need to open other fragments. The final icon needs to open an alert box with options to open other screens.

I am facing two problems:

1. ViewPager loads all the 4 fragments at once and there is a lot of data being processed in the background. I would like to know if there is any way to load content only when the fragment is visible to user. I tried using setPageLimit but it did not work.
2. My second problem is that I would like to ideally open a popup when the last icon is clicked, rather than opening another fragment. IS that possible?

I am not sure if viewPager supports view without fragments.

Comment: Add your activity code

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can make my ViewPager load only one page at a time ie setOffscreenPageLimit(0);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096868/how-can-make-my-viewpager-load-only-one-page-at-a-time-ie-setoffscreenpagelimit)

Comment: In viewpager fragments the current and next fragment will load automatically. You can try setting setoffscreenpagelimit(1); or check if the fragment.isVisible() then load the data.

Comment: Nope adding setOffScreenPageLimit did not work.

Comment: for the popup, how about DialogFragment?

Comment: That's actually a neat idea. Never thought of it! But it actually needs to be more like a popup menu. Click on it and a dropdown opens up

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56056285/7914153) for your first question.