# How to only call onCreateView when fragment is visible?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm using a **ViewPager** with 5 fragments and my problem is that when the first fragment is visible, it already loads the second one.

I read something about `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit();` but default value for this is '1' and can't be set to '0' because **ViewPager** needs this for the swipe animation.

So the second fragment will always be loaded by default.

But my problem is that i have a global Arraylist in both fragments with different values loaded in each fragment and when i'm on fragment one, the values get overwritten because the second fragment is called.

How to only call onCreateView for each fragment when that fragment is visible for the user?

Comment: Use two ArrayLists.

Comment: @TheWanderer is it possible to use one arraylist?

Comment: No, and that's a bad idea in the first place.

Comment: @TheWanderer Because if i have to make new arraylists for each fragment (each fragment has different data) i also have to make new adapters for the recyclerviews in the fragments.

Comment: You just need to make new instances of the same adapter. Using the exact same instance for multiple things is slow and prone to breaking.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would not use a global list. Make a baseFragment if you need to hold a similar type of list. If your goal is to share filtering among fragments, then simply pass the applied filters to each fragment so it knows how to manage its list as it loads or pass the list, but don't use a global that's just asking for trouble.

Second, onCreate is called on the pager on purpose so you can preload some things before it shows on the screen. It's to improve rendering performance as the user swipes from side to side. If you load as the swipe happens, it will be jumpy and bad.

Lastly consider moving your logic to onResume, unless you have good reason not to.
If that doesn't work for you, then monitor the page changing event and call a shared "load" method that you create on each baseFragment that you can simply call and handle your code there.

Answer (score 0):

By using this you can give a try,

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

View pager will load the near by fragments, even if you set setOffscreenPageLimit to 0. Since if the value is less than 1, they will set it as 1.

So onCreate, onCreateView... onResume of the near by fragments will be called before it is visible.

So just load your data in **setUserVisibleHint**.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(getView() != null && isVisibleToUser){
        loadData();
    }
}
```

But there exists a problem. This method(setUserVisibleHint) will be called before the onCreate of our fragment.

If you get the data from arguments.. We will get those data from onCreate or onCreateView of fragment. So the first visible fragment's setUserVisibleHint will be called, without data to load(**getView() != null** from the above method). For this we can use

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);

    // This is because for the first fragment to loadData, since the 
    // setUserVisibleHint is called before the onCreateView of the fragment.

    if(getUserVisibleHint()){
        loadData();
    }

    return view;
}
```

**loadData** is the method which will do data binding part of my fragment.

By doing this, For the first visible fragment loadData will be called from onCreateView and near by fragment it will be called from setUserVisibleHint.