# Android ViewPager Layouts

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have one activity_main_layout with 3 linear layouts inside (layout1, layout2 and layout3). From my MainActivity I want to display specific layouts on buttonClicks.
Like if firstButton is clicked then layout1 is displayed, secondButton displays layout2 and thirdButton displays layout3. I am using viewPager to achieve this. Here is my Code Below:

```
private class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((View) object);
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        int resId = -1;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                resId = R.id.layout1;
                Log.e(TAG, "layout1 called");
                break;
            case 1:
                resId = R.id.layout2;
                Log.e(TAG, "layout2 called");
                break;
            case 2:
                resId = R.id.layout3;
                Log.e(TAG, "layout3 called");
                break;
        }
        return findViewById(resId);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }
}
```

layout1 being the default, it displays on the screen on starting the MainActivity.

When I see the log it displays

```
03-11 14:34:22.776  23506-23506/com.myapp.app E/MainActivity﹕ layout1 called
03-11 14:34:22.777  23506-23506/com.myapp.app E/MainActivity﹕ layout2 called
```

And then when i click secondButton Log shows layout3 called

Any idea on this? I am trying to achieve [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbF8X.png)

Comment: It's an expected behavior, `ViewPager` preloads next page.

Comment: Thanks. the problem is when I click thirdButton, the layout is all blank. 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/XbF8X.png

Comment: Might the problem that you inflate your layouts incorrectly or don't inflate them at all. I would advise you to use `ViewPager` + `Fragments` as pager items, e.g. of implementation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts

Comment: layout1, layout2, layout3 are all in one single file activity_main_layout.

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` will call first 2 pages at initial load, and on page change it will load next page in memory.

In your case `layout1` and `layout2` will be called at initial level and when you move to `layout2` it will load `layout3`.

you can use `setOffScreenPageLimit()` to increase this number but bydefault it will load 2 pages at a time.

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096868/how-can-make-my-viewpager-load-only-one-page-at-a-time-ie-setoffscreenpagelimit) regarding your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution worked for me.

((ViewPager) collection).setOffscreenPageLimit(getCount() - 1);