# How to load only one page at time in view pager

Tags: android

I want to load only one page at a time.

```
viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

is not working.

Comment: Have a look on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44405015/7874047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't do that with a standard ViewPager implementation. If you see sources, you will see, that it sets offscreen page limit to 1, if it is less than 1.

```
public void setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit) {
        if (limit < DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES) { //DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES if 1
            Log.w(TAG, "Requested offscreen page limit " + limit + " too small; defaulting to " +
                    DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES);
            limit = DEFAULT_OFFSCREEN_PAGES;
        }
        if (limit != mOffscreenPageLimit) {
            mOffscreenPageLimit = limit;
            populate();
        }
    }
```

You can try to override this method in your custom class.

Comment: `populate();` method is package private!

Comment: @mallaudin, reflection can call any method, including private and package-visible.

Comment: Yes but that can be fragile.

Comment: @rams don't try to ask questions in comments. If you have question - **ask a question**

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to set the offline page limit to zero?

Having it set to one allows android to pre-emptively load the next view to the view pager improving the user experience and speeding up the load time.

If you must set it to zero then create a custom view pager class that extends ViewPager and then override the setOffScreenPageLimit method