# SlidingTabLayout and ViewPager: how to load the current fragment and not the adjacent one at the same time?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I am trying to implement a sliding tab layout that and each fragment should only load when the tab is selected instead i get the adjacent fragment loading, I have tried setOffScreenPageLimit(1) as my code shows but still the adjacent fragment gets loaded any assistance please ???

```
private SlidingTabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    tabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    if (tabLayout != null) {
        tabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        tabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(R.color.md_amber_600);
    }
```

Comment: as per [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096868/how-can-make-my-viewpager-load-only-one-page-at-a-time-ie-setoffscreenpagelimit), viewpager has to load 2 pages at a time to have sliding better way

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have used setOffScreenPageLimit as 1. It means you are loading only 1 extra screen at a time using `viewPager`, when actually you want to load nothing. It is not possible to set 0 value for `setOffScreenPageLimit` this method, actually you can set it but it will not work.

So, it is not possible to achieve this using view pager. If you still want to perform such a functionality, you can use `FrameLayout` and switch between the fragments based on tab selection.

Below is the tab selection code sample:

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switchToTab(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
```