# Java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: attempt to use the recycled bitmap image android.graphics.Bitmap@5d976e0

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I created PagerAdapter for my application, but the application started to crash with such an error:

> Java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: attempt to use the recycled bitmap image android.graphics.Bitmap@5d976e0

How I can to fix this?

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] allImages;
ImageView imageView;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, int[]images){
    this.context=context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    allImages = images;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return allImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);
    if(imageView != null) {
      ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap().recycle();
    }
    imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
    imageView.setImageResource(allImages[position]);
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}
```

When I select the previous picture in PagerAdapter, the application crashes with this error :

```
08-06 14:59:08.543 2704-2704/com.secret.cardfocus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.secret.cardfocus, PID: 2704
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@28ebced
                                                                    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfCannotDraw(Canvas.java:1271)
                                                                    at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:257)
                                                                    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
                                                                    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17071)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17074)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2443)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16053)
                                                                    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16837)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3764)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3550)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16048)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3748)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3728)
                                                                    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16016)
                                                                    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:656)
                                                                    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:662)
                                                                    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:770)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2796)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2604)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2211)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: You should check the size of your images. Do not use large images if you only need to show them as an icon. Keep the sizes as required.

Comment: One picture weighs no more than 30 kb.

Comment: I converted the images into WEBP format.

Comment: Okay, can you send your source code to me as zip ? I can then fix the issue

Comment: https://github.com/Bobkovn/AndroidProjects/blob/master/CardFocus/src/main/java/com/secret/cardfocus/slider/ImageAdapter.java - PagerAdapter
https://github.com/Bobkovn/AndroidProjects/blob/master/CardFocus/src/main/java/com/secret/cardfocus/FragmentsActivity/TricksActivity.java - activity with PagerAdapter

Comment: https://github.com/Bobkovn/AndroidProjects/blob/master/CardFocus/src/main/java/com/secret/cardfocus/ImageTricks.java - class where i get images for PagerAdapter

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxVj_WYZzv1OYnZ4bFprcC1jQ3M - project

Comment: Okay. Let me check your code. Will let you know in an hour

Comment: At which line and class it crashes >?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096868/how-can-make-my-viewpager-load-only-one-page-at-a-time-ie-setoffscreenpagelimit

Comment: I added logs to my post.

Comment: Unfortunately , the app does not crash on my phone. Check the above comment of mine with link. It may help you.

Comment: On my phone and on the emulator the app crashes. In app there are two adapters, maybe you did not swipe that? Try to swipe the adapter in the activity, which starts after clicking on the ListView.