# How to prevent off-screen pages of ViewPager from loading content when Activity is started?

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I have 3 tabs in `MainActivity`, which loads the content in `ViewPager`. But when the activity starts it loads the contents of second tab also which is off-screen. My tabs are like received message and sent message, and when there are no messages in any, I am showing a Toast that "There are no messages". SO now when the activity starts the default tab "Received" has the messages but still a Toast is shown because there are no "Sent" messages in the second tab.

I want the content of second tab to be loaded only when user selects it.

Comment: May Helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44405015/7874047

Comment: one way is using a custom adapter instead of the `PagerAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

> But when the activity starts it loads the contents of second tab also which is off-screen

`ViewPager` immediately loads additional pages, with an eye towards being able to animate between pages. You cannot prevent `ViewPager` from loading additional pages.

> when there are no messages in any, I am showing a Toast that "There are no messages"

Get rid of the `Toast` and have some inline UI in the tabs ("empty view") that indicates that there are no messages in that tab.

Comment: you are right! but there has to be some tweaks/hacks around

Comment: @vikasdevde: IMHO, you should get rid of the `Toast` regardless. `Toast` is fine for book examples... and not much more. You will not see very many professional apps use a `Toast`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess Im gonna go with your suggestion. Thanks